# Why can't Box<dyn Trait> be pased to a function with &mut Trait as parameter

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I'm sure this has been asked previously but haven't encountered a question that captures the precise scenario here. I have the following code:

```
let mut pool: Box<dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike> = <...>
redis::cmd(COMMAND)
    .arg(LIST)
    .arg(value)
    .query_async(&mut pool)
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

This returns the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike>: redis::aio::ConnectionLike` is not satisfied
   --> svix-server/src/queue/redis.rs:66:30
    |
66  |                 .query_async(&mut pool)
    |                  ----------- ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `redis::aio::ConnectionLike` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike>`
    |                  |
    |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
```

Question 1 -- Why does the error say the trait is not implemented for `Box<dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike>`? Shouldn't it at least say `&Box...`?

Regardless, if I instead try to pass `pool.as_mut()` to `query_async`, I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> svix-server/src/queue/redis.rs:66:30
    |
66  |                 .query_async(pool.as_mut())
    |                  ----------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |                  |
    |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike`
```

Question 2 -- Why is `Sized` required here? Isn't a reference in Rust always `Sized`?

Question 3 -- Is there any way to to pass a `dyn ConnectionLike` to this

The `query_async` method, for reference looks like this:

```
#[inline]
#[cfg(feature = "aio")]
pub async fn query_async<C, T: FromRedisValue>(&self, con: &mut C) -> RedisResult<T>
where
    C: crate::aio::ConnectionLike,
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1 -- Why does the error say the trait is not implemented for `Box<dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike>`? Shouldn't it at least say `&Box`...?

No, because the reference is not part of the generic type `C`.  Rust doesn't name the *entire* type, it only names the parts of the two types that don't match.  The function accepts `&mut C` and `C` is the generic part being matched.  The `Box` type is what is substituted for `C`, and it doesn't implement this trait.

> Question 2 -- Why is `Sized` required here? Isn't a reference in Rust always `Sized`?

A reference is indeed `Sized`, but as noted above we are matching the type `&mut dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike` against `&mut C`.  This results in `C` being `dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike`.

In Rust, generic types have the `Sized` bound *by default.*  You have to explicitly specify the `?Sized` bound to relax this, which the author of this function did not do.  Therefore, `C` must implement `Sized`, and `dyn redis::aio::ConnectionLike` does not.

> Question 3 -- Is there any way to to pass a `dyn ConnectionLike` to this

Possibly, but not directly.  You would need to implement a type that wraps either a reference-to-`dyn ConnectionLike` or a `Box<dyn ConnectionLike>` and pass that instead.  Something like:

```
struct BoxedConnectionLike(Box<dyn ConnectionLike>);

impl ConnectionLike for BoxedConnectionLike {
    // Implement proxy functions for the trait.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is Sized required here?

```rust
pub async fn query_async<C, T: FromRedisValue>(&self, con: &mut C) -> RedisResult<T>
where
    C: crate::aio::ConnectionLike,
```

All type parameters in Rust have an implicit `Sized` bound unless they opt out — the compiler acts as if `C: Sized` was specified.

Possibly this code could be generalized to allow unsized types (written `C: ?Sized`); I don't know.

> Isn't a reference in Rust always Sized?

Yes, but the implicit bound is on the referent, `C`.

> Is there any way to to pass a dyn ConnectionLike to this

You need to define, or use an existing, type which implements the `ConnectionLike` trait and *contains* a `dyn ConnectionLike`, then pass a mutable reference to that type.

The cleanest approach is to use Box itself, by having the implementation

```rust
impl<C: ?Sized> ConnectionLike for Box<C>
where
    C: ConnectionLike
{ ... }
```

But, only the crate defining the trait can add that `impl`.